# Git: How to reset hard to refspec

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

Im doing some work with gerrit, and with gerrit you only get the refspec of a commit. Something like:

```
refs/changes/01/15501/2
```

How do I reset hard to this?

I tried to play nice

```
[me@server code ((7deac0e...))]$ git reset --hard refs/changes/01/15501/2
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/changes/01/15501/2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

This was not the best error message, so I tried agian...

```
[me@server code ((7deac0e...))]$ git reset --hard -- refs/changes/01/15501/2
fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.
```

I dont need to use reset --hard, but it would work well in my situation. My script runs in the code repo, but I have no idea what state it is in. There is only one file which is reliable and doesn't change, which is the reset_to_gerrit script.

I tell that script to reset to some refspec, and that puts my code repo in a place that i atleast know what to expect. There is a very high possibility of merge conflicts between the original and final state, and reset hard should avoid all of that.

Comment: Incidentally, that's just a ref rather than a refspec.  A refspec describes a mapping between a source and destination ref, and might look like `master:other-branch`.  (If you just put a single ref name in a place when a refspec is expected, git will assume that you mean the same ref on either side of the colon, but in this case `git reset --hard` is just expecting a ref.)

Comment: Can you include the output of `git show-ref` in your question?

Comment: Are you trying to do a hard reset on the remote?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in two steps.

1. First fetch the change
2. Then hard reset to FETCH_HEAD

Something like:

```
git fetch origin refs/changes/01/15501/2
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```